# Installing Neovim through Linuxbrew on AWS

Tags: neovim, linuxbrew

I'm trying to install neovim with linuxbrew on AWS, but I keep getting the following messages, and I can't figure it out :/.

> /home/ec2-user/.linuxbrew/bin/libtool: line 10548: /usr/bin/gcc-4.8: No such file or directory

```
~/dotfiles$ brew install neovim
==> Installing neovim from neovim/neovim
==> Downloading https://github.com/neovim/neovim/archive/v0.1.4.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /home/ec2-user/.cache/Homebrew/neovim-0.1.4.tar.gz
==> Downloading https://github.com/libuv/libuv/archive/v1.8.0.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /home/ec2-user/.cache/Homebrew/neovim--libuv-1.8.0.tar.gz
==> Downloading https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack-c/archive/cpp-1.0.0.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /home/ec2-user/.cache/Homebrew/neovim--msgpack-1.0.0.tar.gz
==> Downloading https://raw.githubusercontent.com/neovim/deps/master/opt/LuaJIT-2.0.4.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /home/ec2-user/.cache/Homebrew/neovim--luajit-2.0.4.tar.gz
==> Downloading https://github.com/keplerproject/luarocks/archive/5d8a16526573b36d5b22aa74866120c998466697.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /home/ec2-user/.cache/Homebrew/neovim--luarocks-998466697.tar.gz
==> Downloading https://github.com/mauke/unibilium/archive/v1.2.0.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /home/ec2-user/.cache/Homebrew/neovim--unibilium-1.2.0.tar.gz
==> Downloading http://www.leonerd.org.uk/code/libtermkey/libtermkey-0.18.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /home/ec2-user/.cache/Homebrew/neovim--libtermkey-0.18.tar.gz
==> Downloading https://github.com/neovim/libvterm/archive/1b745d29d45623aa8d22a7b9288c7b0e331c7088.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /home/ec2-user/.cache/Homebrew/neovim--libvterm-7088.tar.gz
==> Downloading https://github.com/jemalloc/jemalloc/releases/download/4.0.2/jemalloc-4.0.2.tar.bz2
Already downloaded: /home/ec2-user/.cache/Homebrew/neovim--jemalloc-4.0.2.tar.bz2
==> Building third-party dependencies.
==> cmake ../third-party -DUSE_BUNDLED_BUSTED=OFF -DUSE_BUNDLED_LUV=OFF -DUSE_EXISTING_SRC_DIR=ON -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE=-DNDEBUG -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE=-DNDEBUG -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/ec2-user/
==> make VERBOSE=1
Last 15 lines from /home/ec2-user/.cache/Homebrew/Logs/neovim/02.make:
libtool: compile:  /home/ec2-user/.linuxbrew/bin/gcc-5 -I. -Wall -std=c99 -fPIC -c uninames.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/uninames.o
libtool: compile:  /home/ec2-user/.linuxbrew/bin/gcc-5 -I. -Wall -std=c99 -fPIC -c uninames.c -o uninames.o >/dev/null 2>&1
libtool --mode=compile --tag=CC /home/ec2-user/.linuxbrew/bin/gcc-5 -I. -DTERMINFO_DIRS='"/etc/terminfo:/lib/terminfo:/usr/share/terminfo:/usr/lib/terminfo:/usr/local/share/terminfo:/usr/local/lib/terminfo"' -Wall -std=c99 -fPIC  -o uniutil.lo -c uniutil.c
libtool: compile:  /home/ec2-user/.linuxbrew/bin/gcc-5 -I. -DTERMINFO_DIRS=\"/etc/terminfo:/lib/terminfo:/usr/share/terminfo:/usr/lib/terminfo:/usr/local/share/terminfo:/usr/local/lib/terminfo\" -Wall -std=c99 -fPIC -c uniutil.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/uniutil.o
libtool: compile:  /home/ec2-user/.linuxbrew/bin/gcc-5 -I. -DTERMINFO_DIRS=\"/etc/terminfo:/lib/terminfo:/usr/share/terminfo:/usr/lib/terminfo:/usr/local/share/terminfo:/usr/local/lib/terminfo\" -Wall -std=c99 -fPIC -c uniutil.c -o uniutil.o >/dev/null 2>&1
libtool --mode=link --tag=CC /home/ec2-user/.linuxbrew/bin/gcc-5 -L/home/ec2-user/.linuxbrew/lib -Wl,--dynamic-linker=/home/ec2-user/.linuxbrew/lib/ld.so -Wl,-rpath,/home/ec2-user/.linuxbrew/lib -rpath '/tmp/neovim-20160518-12137-13p0ite/neovim-0.1.4/deps-build/usr/lib' -version-info 3:0:3 -o libunibilium.la unibilium.lo uninames.lo uniutil.lo
libtool: link: /usr/bin/gcc-4.8 -shared  -fPIC -DPIC  .libs/unibilium.o .libs/uninames.o .libs/uniutil.o   -L/home/ec2-user/.linuxbrew/lib  -Wl,--dynamic-linker=/home/ec2-user/.linuxbrew/lib/ld.so -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/home/ec2-user/.linuxbrew/lib   -Wl,-soname -Wl,libunibilium.so.0 -o .libs/libunibilium.so.0.3.0
/home/ec2-user/.linuxbrew/bin/libtool: line 10548: /usr/bin/gcc-4.8: No such file or directory
make[3]: *** [libunibilium.la] Error 127
make[3]: Leaving directory `/tmp/neovim-20160518-12137-13p0ite/neovim-0.1.4/deps-build/build/src/unibilium'
make[2]: *** [build/src/unibilium-stamp/unibilium-build] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/tmp/neovim-20160518-12137-13p0ite/neovim-0.1.4/deps-build'
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/unibilium.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/tmp/neovim-20160518-12137-13p0ite/neovim-0.1.4/deps-build'
make: *** [all] Error 2

READ THIS: https://github.com/Linuxbrew/brew/blob/master/share/doc/homebrew/Troubleshooting.md#troubleshooting
If reporting this issue please do so at (not Homebrew/brew):
  https://github.com/neovim/homebrew-neovim/issues

These open issues may also help:
Neovim Fails to Install on Standalone Linuxbrew: libmsgpack.so Error https://github.com/neovim/homebrew-neovim/issues/156
 Neovim failing to build with homebrew on OS X 10.9.5  https://github.com/neovim/homebrew-neovim/issues/153
Can't install via homebrew-neovim if luarocks path is set explicitly https://github.com/neovim/homebrew-neovim/issues/149
Error when trying to install neovim in my Ubuntu 14.04 virtual machine. https://github.com/neovim/homebrew-neovim/issues/134
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. It is a problem of the libtool formula
https://github.com/Linuxbrew/homebrew-core/issues/376

I fixed by doing

```
brew update
brew reinstall -s libtool
brew install neovim/neovim/neovim
```